# How to create and point to nested components in Angular 8

Tags: angular, nested, angular8, angular-components

I have an Angular application which has the following structure

```
|— src
    |— app
        |— user
            |— collection
                |— collection.component.html
                |— collection.component.scss
                |— collection.component.ts
            |— user.component.html
            |— user.component.scss
            |— user.component.ts
    ...
```

**How can I point to the collection component right from the user component?**

Comment: The IDE itself gives autosuggestion. I hope you are using visual studio code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selector tag of the connection component inside the template of the user component.

If the connection component takes any `@Input` parameters, then make sure to provide them when using it inside another component.

Note - this works if both the components are declared in the same module

You can refer to [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPLjY-9k-zE).

Answer (score 0):

In your user.component.ts, you can

```
import { CollectionComponent } from './collection/collection.component'
```

Comment: then how will i use it

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper Looks like you need to go a long way before getting answer to this question. Try learning angular through an online course and the answers will unfold automatically.